# Gulp Sass - no errors to console

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have the following code in my glup.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./stylesheets/*.{scss,sass}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss',['default']);
});
```

If I have valid sass in my style.scss file it correctly generates the style.css and style.css.map files, however, if errors are in the style.scss file no output is propogating to the console.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tasks named `default`. Name the first `sass` and change your watch task to execute the `sass` command.

Also, my error logging looks like this, with and extra `.sync()` method call:

```
.pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
```